# How to implement a multicore processors when using regsubset exhaustive method in Rstudio server

Tags: r, rstudio, multicore, rstudio-server

How would I rewrite my code so that I can implement the use of multicore on an Rstudio server to run `regsubsets` from the leaps package using the "exhaustive" method?  The data has 1200 variables and 9000 obs so the code has been shortened here:

```
model<-regsubsets(price~x + y + z + a + b +  ...., data=sample,
                  nvmax=500,  method=c("exhaustive"))
```

Our server is a quad core 7.5 gb ram, is that enough for an equation like this?

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your second question I would say: just give it a try and see. In general, a 1200 times 9000 dataset is not particularly large, but wether or not it works also depends on what `regsubsets` does under the hood.

In general, the approach here would be to cut up the problem in pieces and run each of the piece on a core, in your case 4 cores. The paralellization works most effective if the processes that we run on a core takes some time (e.g. 10 min). If it takes very little time, the overhead of parallelization will only serve to increase the time the total analysis takes. Creating a cluster on your server is quite easy using e.g. `SNOW` (available on CRAN). The approach I often use is to create a cluster using the `doSNOW` package, and then use the functions from the `plyr` package. [A blog post](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/11/14/parallelization-using-plyr-loading-objects-and-packages-into-worker-nodes/) I wrote recently provides some background and example code.

In your specific case, if `regsubsets` does not support parallelization out of the box, you'll have to do some coding yourself. I think a variable selection method such as `regsubsets` requires the entire dataset to be used, therefore I think solving the parallelization by running several regsubsets in parallel is not feasible. So I think you'll have to adapt the function to include the parallelization. Somewhere inside the function the different variable selections are evaluated, there you could send those evaluations to different cores. Do take care that if such an evaluation takes only little time, the parallelization overhead will only slow your analysis down. In that case you need to send a group of evaluations to each core in order to increase the time spent on each node, decreasing the amount of overhead from parallelization.

Comment: Crunching is passed on to FORTRAN, so the parallelization will have to  be implemented just before that - or implement parallelization in the FORTRAN code itself.

Comment: For a typical problem, how long does the crunching take? Looping over the variables, is that done in FORTRAN or in R? Parallelization in FORTRAN might be an even bigger challenge than doing it in R.

Comment: What I can gather from the source code of the package - R is just a wrapper around FORTRAN code. I would wait for a FORTRAN savvy person to look at the FORTRAN source and comment on how parallelizable the code really is. Interesting problem, though.

Comment: @cconell, Paul Hiemstra - Know this is an old question, but were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @anna I did not try to actually do this, only provided the advice. Maybe the OP has more for you.